# Cocos2d-x ccTouchesBegan выдает ошибку

Tags: cocos2d

Компилятор ругается на строки:

```
virtual void ccTouchesBegan(CCSet* pTouches, CCEvent*      event); 
virtual void ccTouchesMoved(CCSet* pTouches, CCEvent*      event);
virtual void ccTouchesEnded(CCSet* pTouches, CCEvent*      event);
```

> IntelliSense: невозможно
> переопределить final функция
> "cocos2d::Layer::ccTouchesBegan"
> (объявлено в строке 73 из
> "C:\Cocos\frameworks\cocos2d-x-3.4rc1\cocos\2d....\cocos\2d/CCLayer.h") f:\cocos2d\cocos2d-x\NEW_PROJECTS_DIR\MyGame\Classes\HelloWorldScene.h  18  15  MyGame

В чем проблема?

Comment: нашел проблему ccTouchesBegan устарело для третий версии движка.Нужно использовать onTouchesBegan с listener

Answer (score 2):

Методы, которые позволяет переопределить кокос (версия 3.4).

Заходи в CCLayer.h и там смотри, что тебе нужно оттуда взять!

```
virtual bool onTouchBegan(Touch *touch, Event *unused_event) override;

virtual void onTouchMoved(Touch *touch, Event *unused_event) override;

virtual void onTouchEnded(Touch *touch, Event *unused_event) override;

virtual void onTouchCancelled(Touch *touch, Event *unused_event) override;

virtual void onTouchesBegan(const std::vector<Touch*>& touches, Event *unused_event) override;

virtual void onTouchesMoved(const std::vector<Touch*>& touches, Event *unused_event) override;

virtual void onTouchesEnded(const std::vector<Touch*>& touches, Event *unused_event) override;

virtual void onTouchesCancelled(const std::vector<Touch*>&touches, Event *unused_event) override;
```